# Enable Scrolling when using ZSH on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, scrolling

I recently switched to Z-Shell (`zsh`) on my Mac using the Prezto framework. I like `zsh` a lot and it has a lot of useful features that I am using. However, one of the capabilities I really miss is the ability to use the mouse scroll action to scroll through `man` pages and `less` output. I was able to do this by default when using `bash` in *Terminal.app*.

How do I duplicate this functionality and enable scrolling in `zsh` on my Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in the default options set by Prezto. See:

```
# Set the default Less options.
# Mouse-wheel scrolling has been disabled by -X (disable screen clearing).
# Remove -X and -F (exit if the content fits on one screen) to enable it.
#  export LESS='-F -g -i -M -R -S -w -X -z-4'  ### Initial
export LESS='-g -i -M -R -S -w -z-4'
```

The second export allows me to scroll through the output of `man` and `less`.